# get "Property not in account? when checking robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt, google-search-console

I see many URLs with status Excluded in search console google, when I click on "TEST ROBOTS.TXT BLOCKING" I get following error:

```
Property not in account

You are verified to see sc-domain://, but it's not in your account.
```

when I click on `add property now` nothing will happen

when I change URL in the browser from `https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/robots-testing-tool?siteUrl=sc-domain%3Amysite.com&path=&utm_source=search_console&utm_campaign=index-panel&hl=en` to `https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/robots-testing-tool?siteUrl=https://%3Amysite.com&path=&utm_source=search_console&utm_campaign=index-panel&hl=en` it asks me to add the URL as a property again; while I already added domain property

I also cleared my robots.txt to be sure nothing is blocked yet after more than 8 days I see about 1.5M URL blocked in search console

Comment: Where do you see the "TEST ROBOTS.TXT BLOCKING" option?

Comment: @TonyMcCreath When I click on any of links in excluded section a box from right open, with three elements 1- link of the page 2- Inspect Url 3- TEST ROBOTS.TXT BLOCKING

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask questions like this there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to duplicate the issue. Seems that that tool does not work when you have verified at the domain level. The domain level properties are reasonably new and don't support all features yet. But it should provide a better response.

A work around would be to also verify at the url prefix level where the tool should work.

I've reported the issue under the help->send feedback option.

Comment: the problem with URL prefix level is that my site has more than 100 subdomains, I think it requires to add them individually, which might result in a messy console, I'm using domain property from late 2019 how much do you think it take to add this functionality?

Comment: No idea on how long they will take. They seem to be gradually adding features.

Answer (score 3):

Change it from `siteUrl=sc-domain%3Aexample.com` to `siteUrl=https://www.example.com`

That worked for me.

See https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/19217968?hl=en

Answer (score 2):

Yeah I have searched a lot robot.txt is working when I check the URL of robot.txt but when I test it in the search console it didn't open in the tester tool even I am a verified owner of the domain. So adding the URL prefixes is the only solution to test the robot.txt in GSC.